# Security - Async Models - Firebase

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase, ember-cli, emberfire

After seeming to bang my head on a wall for what seems to be a simple problem I thought it best to ask for some help.

I am creating an EmberFire application that allows users to authenticate using the simple login. Once authenticated the user can store particular items for later retrieval.

I have models defined as so:

USER:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  dateOfBirth: DS.attr('date'),
  registeredAt: DS.attr('date'),
  compentencies: DS.hasMany('competency', { async: true })
});
```

COMPETENCY:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  endDate: DS.attr('date'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true })
});
```

These are stored in the firebase db in a denormalised for as I would like them to be.

[image]
My issue arises on retrieval of persisted data. I am not sure how I am supposed to lock the competencies down to a particular user?

The way the rules cascade in FireBase I am not sure if this is even possible in this form but it does not seem right that I would have to store each competency in an embedded form under each user node.

I know that I could just allow read access to all 'Competency' models with this.store.find('competency') and then filter them on the client but that does not fit the security I would expect.

Any help would be great thanks.

Ryan

Comment: 1) Your backend may sent competencies as ids `{user: {competencies: [1,2]}}` 2) Your backend knows what user is requesting info, right? You may answer to `this.store.find('competency')` with competencies of only currently logged user. This is an easy, secure and correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I do not understand how scope the response to `this.store.find('competency')` I thought that would make a request to /competencies on the server, that in Firebase can return all the competencies or none?

Comment: My backend knows which user is requesting the info. However, scoping the response is another matter.

Comment: Yes, that would make a request to /competencies. And server may determine user and send all competencies **for logged in user**

Comment: I understand that however how can I get Firebase to send all competencies for that logged in user only? I was sure this was not possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, so can't help with that part

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Did you run into something not covered in the [security guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is my data secure with firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143257/how-is-my-data-secure-with-firebase)

Comment: Hi Kato, I believe so, I don't understand how to allow users hit other models that belong to them in a denormalised data structure without opening up that full branch of the DB, therefore allowing access to anybody.

Comment: I have ran into this problem as well. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

To only allow read access to a competency if the competency belongs to the user who is currently logged in you can use `$competencyId` (you can replace "competencyId" with any valid string). Using `$competencyId` limits access to a specific node under `competencies/` instead of allowing access to the entire tree.

```
"rules": {
  "competencies": {
    "$competencyId": {
      ".read": "data.child('user').val() === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```